# C pointer query

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
struct list{
int a,b,c;
struct list *next, *previous;
}
```

Now I need to know the difference in memory allocated in the two scenarios:

```
1) struct list *ptr = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list*));
```

and

```
2) struct list *ptr = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

Comment: You have pasted the same line twice? (1) & (2) are same.

Comment: @GAURAV please update your question, it seems to be written wrong

Comment: And it's not `Struct` but `struct`.

Comment: @all downvoters OP has updated question so revert back your downvote and welcome new coder to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typed the same line twice. Both are same.

```
struct list *ptr = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list*));
```

Here you have allocated the memory whose size is `sizeof(struct list*)`

Here struct list * is a pointer to type struct list. so size of any pointer on 32 bit machine is 4 byte and on 64 bit machine its 8 byte.

so you have allocated that much memory.

I think in second option you may be want to ask about this

```
struct list *ptr = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

Here you have allocated memory whose size is the size of that `struct list.`

Comment: @GAURAVJAIN Welcome to stackoverflow. Have a Happy coding..!!